# eslint not running in VS code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, eslint

I moved to a new machine (both macOs) with my two Javascript Projects, one npm package and one Meteor project. In the npm package eslint does not show any errors, whereas in the Meteor project eslint works as expected. On my old machine, there wasn't such a problem with exact the same package.json and .eslintrc and VS code version.

What I tried till now:

Adding these lines to settings.json of VS code:

```
"eslint.validate": [
                "vue",
                "html",
                "javascript",
                "js",
                "typescript",
                "javascriptreact",
                "typescriptreact"
            ],
```

I even copied the complete settings.json to the new machine

Installing eslint globally and uninstall it (neither brought the solution)

Updating eslint from 3.19.0 -> 7.1.0

Comment: Which version of NodeJS do you run?

Comment: Have you installed eslint vscode extension?

Comment: `node --version`

`v8.9.0`

Comment: Yes, eslint vscode extension is installed and active.